My emulator screen too frequently gets freezed or locked
While updating my Android Studio manually, I deleted and updated some files, which has caused issues with my emulator in Android Studio freezing or locking up easily and too frequently. As soon as I open or resize the terminal, it freezes.
Yes, I found one solution on Stack Overflow: to open the emulator files in Explorer and delete the 'hardware-qemu.ini.lock' file and other lock files. However, this is not a permanent solution because deleting these files every time is frustrating, and even if I do so, it gets booted again, wasting too much of my time.
I even tried deleting emulators and again re-installing but still it is also not working.
So please help me solve these issues.

I get the same issue when using an Android 13 emulator. Using older versions fixes this.

thanks @BilalNaeem, but I started experiencing this issue once I tampered with the Android Studio's files.
